# Link arrays for UISearchController in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search

I m using a UISearchController to let the user search though my data (these comes from XML and been parsed to arrays), now i want to add more then one UILabel into my Cell, but these UILabel Information comes from different arrays.

As soon as i update my Search, the 2. array does not get sorted the same way like the first does.

```
AP = ["FIRST1","FIRST2","FIRST3","FIRST4","FIRST5"]
APSecound = ["SEC1","SEC2","SEC3","SEC4","SEC5"]
var filteredTableDataAP = [String]()
var filteredTableDataAPSecound = [String]()


func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableDataIcao.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (AP as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableDataAP = array as! [String]
    //i think here i some how could set index of "filteredTableDataAP = filteredTableDataAPSecound" so they been filtered like the same shema



    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


Override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCellSearch", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCellSearch


    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.APLB.text = filteredTableDataAP[indexPath.row]
        cell.APSecoundLB.text = filteredTableDataAPSecound[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.APLB.text = AP[indexPath.row]
        cell.APSecoundLB.text = APSecound[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

On first run without searching the cell looks fine like

> (FIRST1)(SEC1) 
>   (FIRST2)(SEC2)  
>   (FIRST3)(SEC3)  
>   (FIRST4)(SEC4)

But once i search for "4" the cell looks like

> (FIRST4)(SEC1)

is there any easy way to "keep the position of the second array like the one of the first"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i have used is below

you have two array :

```
        AP = ["FIRST1","FIRST2","FIRST3","FIRST4","FIRST5"]
        APSecound = ["SEC1","SEC2","SEC3","SEC4","SEC5"]
        var getIndex = 0

        if (self.SearchController.active) // check if SearchController isactive
        {

            //This will get the index of main array
             getIndex = AP.indexOf(filteredsearchPost[indexPath.row])! 
            //According to example index should be 1 for "FIRST2"


    .      cell.APSecoundLB.text = APSecound[getIndex] 
//set it with the retrived index and its done
//it will print "SEC2"


        }else {
           getIndex = indexPath.row
          cell.APLB.text = AP[getIndex]
          cell.APSecoundLB.text = APSecound[getIndex]
          //Do the else part here
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you just filtered the `AP` not filtered `APSecound`

```
 let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
 let array = (AP as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
 let arraySecond = (APSecound as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

 filteredTableDataAP = array as! [String]
filteredTableDataAPSecound = arraySecond as! [String]
```

or you can use  `filteredResault: [[String: String?]]` , `[String: String?]` is the `Dictionary`, `filteredResault` is `Dictionary array`. dict like `["AP": "FIRST1", "APSecound": "SEC1"]`

Comment: He doesn't want to search in second array ... So it won't work